# c# autocomplete colors, images?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, colors

Does anybody know if there is a way for the autocomplete customsource is able to contain colors or images? I would like to be able to distinguish different suggestions by color or maybe even image. It can be similar to the new firefox autocomplete addressbar.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably see functionality like this in VS2010 or in plugins for it. VS2010's editor is written in WPF, so there will be much better possibilities for rich features like the one you desire.

Unfortunately, I don't think anything like that exists for VS2008.